# Is the Microsoft Graph API for Excel publicly accessible?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I came across a Microsoft Channel 9 video from November 2015 that showed off the new Excel REST API, which is part of the Microsoft Graph API.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2015/315

I can work with the Graph API with no issues but as soon as I try to do anything with the Excel APIs shown in the video and documented on the Excel Rest github repository (https://github.com/sumurthy/excelrest) I'm greeted with the following error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported segment type.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "23124fc5-8f81-49a4-8f82-aa711aa00491",
        "date": "2016-03-09T15:55:19"
    }
}
```

I've been using the Graph Explorer from Microsoft (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) for experimentation.

When I call the Graph API to see an XLSX file's properties, it works just fine:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/01D5O3XCOK7C7NVF2BQJEJCUBXR57WF6Y6

But when I call the Graph API to see the XLSX file's worksheets (as shown in the video and documentation), it fails:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/01D5O3XCOK7C7NVF2BQJEJCUBXR57WF6Y6/workbook/worksheets

Both the video and the github repository are created by the Program Manager of Office Extensibility at Microsoft so they are legit.

In watching the video again, it seems that the presenter wasn't actually using the regular Graph API available at https://graph.microsoft.com but instead his Fiddler calls seem to be to the obscure http://suramamxl.redmonst.corp.microsoft.com host.

I've spent about 3 days in total trying to get anything like what is shown in the video to work to no avail. I can usually find tons of information about any topic on Google but it's as if there is no information (aside from the Channel 9 video) available.

At the end of the video, the presenter suggests (amongst other things) engage on stackoverflow with regards to the API.

Does anyone know if the API is publicly accessible and, if so, how to access it?

Any help would be most greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in the Excel REST API, we had some set backs on publically releasing the preview of the API during December, but the good news is that we are really close to making it publically accessible in the /beta endpoint, stay tuned to our announcements and updates in the changelog.

Comment: Where can I find that changelog?

Comment: graph.microsoft.io/changelog.

Comment: Got the same problem. And your comment absolutly not answer to the problem. This is now the v1.0, and seems that API is still unavailable from public calls.

Answer (score 4):

I am happy to share the Excel REST API is generally available from today. Please find more information here http://dev.office.com/blogs/power-your-apps-with-the-new-excel-rest-api

Thanks,
Sky

Answer (score 2):

the changelog Yina was referring to lives here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/changelog